# How to SELECT name, max(value from a table joined on name)?

Tags: mysql, sql

**Summary**: I have a forum with a `forums` table and a `posts` table. Every post has a unique ID (an auto-incrementing integer), and every post references a `forums.id`.

I'm trying to issue a `SELECT` query that retrieves all the forum names, all the forum IDs, and then the highest `posts.id` associated with that forum.

It's possible that there are *no* posts in a forum and in that case I want the max-posts-id to be 0.

**Forums** table:

```
| ID | Name |
|----|------|
| 1  | Dogs |
| 2  | Food |
| 3  | Work |
```

**Posts** table:

```
| ID | Forum_ID | Author | Text |
|----|----------|--------|------|
| 42 | 1        | Mr. S  | foo  |
| 43 | 3        | Mr. Y  | bar  |
| 44 | 1        | Ms. X  | baz  |
| 45 | 2        | Ms. A  | foo  |
| 46 | 1        | Mr. M  | foo  |
| 47 | 3        | Ms. A  | bar  |
| 48 | 2        | Mr. L  | baz  |
```

Desired result:

```
| Forum_ID | Name | Max_Posts_ID |
|----------|------|--------------|
| 1        | Dogs | 46           |
| 2        | Food | 48           |
| 3        | Work | 47           |
```

My attempt

```
SELECT 
    forums.id AS id,
    forums.name AS name,
    COALESCE(MAX(SELECT id FROM posts WHERE forums.id = ?), 0)
JOIN
    posts ON forums.id = posts.forum_id;
```

But I don't think I can pass a parameter to my nested `SELECT` query, I don't think that's the right approach. What should I do instead?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `LEFT JOIN` and aggregation:

```
SELECT f.id      AS id,
       f.name    AS name,
       COALESCE(MAX(p.id),0) AS Max_Posts_ID
FROM Forums f
LEFT JOIN Posts p
  ON f.Id = p.forum_id
GROUP BY f.id, f.name
ORDER BY f.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution to your problem:

**MySQL**

```
SELECT fs.id AS Forum_ID ,
       fs.name AS Name,
       IFNULL(MAX(ps.ID),0) AS Max_Posts_ID  
FROM forums fs
LEFT JOIN posts ps 
ON fs.id = ps.forum_id
GROUP BY fs.id,fs.name;
```

**Link** To the MySQL Demo:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a18ab2/1

**MSSQL**

```
SELECT fs.id AS Forum_ID ,
       fs.name AS Name,
       ISNULL(MAX(ps.ID),0) AS Max_Posts_ID  
FROM forums fs
LEFT JOIN posts ps 
ON fs.id = ps.forum_id
GROUP BY fs.id,fs.name;
```

**Link** To the MSSQL Demo:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a18ab/2

**OUTPUT:**

```
Forum_ID    Name    Max_Posts_ID
 1          Dogs     46
 2          Food     48
 3          Work     47
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for. (`COALESCE()` is ANSI SQL, `IFNULL()` is not.)

Comment: @jarlh Is it okay Now.

Comment: @GreenTriangle Try this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let me correct your current attempt with *correlation* subquery

```
SELECT 
       id AS id,
       name AS name,
       (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(ID), 0) FROM Posts where forum_id = f.Id) AS Max_Posts_ID 
FROM Forums f
```

Corrections :

- Your outer query wasn't have `from` clause
- Subquery wasn't referenced the *outer query*  column `id` with `Posts` forum_id

Answer (score 0):

Link to Code : http://tpcg.io/pI2HO5

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

/* Create a table called NAMES */
CREATE TABLE Forums (Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name text);

/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO Forums VALUES(1,'Dogs');
INSERT INTO Forums VALUES(2,'Food');
INSERT INTO Forums VALUES(3,'Work');

/* Create a table called NAMES */
CREATE TABLE Posts (Id integer PRIMARY KEY, forId integer);

/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO Posts VALUES(42,1);
INSERT INTO Posts VALUES(43,3);
INSERT INTO Posts VALUES(64,1);
INSERT INTO Posts VALUES(45,2);
INSERT INTO Posts VALUES(46,1);
INSERT INTO Posts VALUES(47,3);
INSERT INTO Posts VALUES(48,2);
INSERT INTO Posts VALUES(51,2);


COMMIT;

/* Display all the records from the table */
SELECT Distinct forId as Forum_Id, Posts.id, (Select Name from Forums where forId == Forums.id) FROM Posts,Forums GROUP BY Posts.forId;

Output : 

1|64|Dogs
2|51|Food
3|47|Work
```